# Design pattern to avoid returning interfaces

Tags: go, design-patterns

My application has the following model that I simplified on purpose, and I think there is a lot of code smell in the way I am using interfaces:

1. Libraries have Collections
2. Collections have Items
3. Libraries know where the location if Item is.

Let's say I have ten libraries (that will be implemented in separated packages, each one with its specificities).

I want to manipulate the libraries in handlers to serve requests. So, I defined the following interfaces:

```
type Library interface {
    ListCollections(prefix string) []Collection
    GetItemLocation(item Item) string    
}
type Collection interface {
    SearchItems(query string) []Item
}
type Item interface {
    Name() string
    Summary() string
}
```

I cannot define an `Item` struct as each one is different. However, with respect to the outer world, having the `Item` interface is sufficient.

As you can see, I have methods returning interfaces and I don't really like it. Moreover, I struggle with, in this example, the `GetItemLocation` part: it expects an Item, but I need to access fields of the Item (specific to each collection) so it forces me to type cast the argument inside the method.

Which patterns could I use to breakdown this complexity and write more diomatic go code?

Comment: Having to use type assertion in `GetItemLocation()` doesn't seem like a showstopper to me. Also consider not expecting `Item` but just the ID of the item (or whatever is used to identify it).

Comment: The only problem with the assertion is it turns what should be compile-time type safety into a runtime error.